# Ploting categorical variable to get numbers at the top of the bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a small sample of my data just to demonstrate the the plot of interest

```html
df<-read.table (text=" P    U   W
A   F   F
M   M   F
N   F   F
A   F   F
M   M   F
N   M   F
Q   M   F
Q   M   F
R   F   M
R   F   M
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following plot in ggplot2

[image]

The plots and numbers at the top of the bars are incorrect. I just wanted to demonstrate the plot of interest. Please do not use loop if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lack of detail and specificity in the question, it's not possible for me to be sure of what you're looking for. Perhaps it is something like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<-read.table (text=" P    U   W
A   F   F
M   M   F
N   F   F
A   F   F
M   M   F
N   M   F
Q   M   F
Q   M   F
R   F   M
R   F   M
", header=TRUE)

x <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(U, W), ~paste0(cur_column(), .x))) %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "series",
               values_to = "group",
               cols = c(U, W)) %>%
  group_by(group, P) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

x %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = P, y = n, fill = P)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n),
            vjust = -0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, sorry it does not reflect the plot of interest

Comment: If you could please refine the question to make it clearer, I am sure I or someone else could help you.

Comment: I feel like getting a downvote for this, given that there is no way to go from the provided data to the example plot, is quite harsh...

Comment: Thanks, Matt- if you look at the plot of interest, you will see a lack of the numbers at the bars. This simply indicates you did not address it. I do believe that the question is very clear and the output is so clear. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I do not know if this is what you are looking for, but perhaps this is closer. If this is not what you are looking for, perhaps adding some detail to your question may help.

Comment: Yes, it's great thanks